# How can I send json formatted log entries to Loggly with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, monolog, loggly

I've followed what I think is the correct setup for Loggly as a Monolog channel with Laravel 5.6 but I keep getting strings of text instead of json searchable entries. E.g:

> [2018-07-27 14:50:20] local.INFO: array (
> 'foo' => 'bar',
> )

This is from the 'unparsed' property of the Loggly entry. Not a valid json by any stretch!!!

Here are some relevant snippets of code to show how the loggly channel is set up and how I trigger the log entry.

**config/logging.php:**

```
'loggly' => [
        'driver' => 'monolog',
        'handler' => Monolog\Handler\LogglyHandler::class,
        'with' => [
            'token' => env('LOGGLY_KEY'),
            'tag' => str_replace(' ', '_', env('APP_NAME') . '_' . env('APP_ENV')),
        ]
    ]
```

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/', function(){
Log::info(['foo' => 'bar']);
return view('welcome');
```

});

**from composer.json:**

```
"laravel/framework": "5.6.21",
"monolog/monolog": "^1.23",
```

I thought maybe upgrading to a more recent monolog version might help but ran into this when trying to update monolog via composer:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - laravel/framework v5.6.21 requires monolog/monolog ~1.12 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.x-dev].
> - laravel/framework v5.6.21 requires monolog/monolog ~1.12 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.x-dev].
> - laravel/framework v5.6.21 requires monolog/monolog ~1.12 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.x-dev].
> - Can only install one of: monolog/monolog[2.x-dev, 1.x-dev].
> - Installation request for monolog/monolog ^2.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[2.x-dev].
> - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.6.21 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.21].

What am I missing? Shouldn't Monolog be sending my log output as json to Loggly? Looking atLogglyHandler it uses LogglyFormatter which extends JsonFormatter. That seems sensible but in the end the output is a string. What gives?

Comment: I think it needs to be "handler_with" instead of "with", and that only supports constructur arguments for the LogglyHandler class - so the "tag"-line is not working here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After diving deep into monolog and json formatter the fix ended up being really simple. The first parameter is a text value and the **second** parameter can contain an associative array that gets translated to json and is searchable in Loggly.

```
Log::info('Home Page Loaded',['foo' => 'bar']);
```

Comment: This is genius, exactly what I have just been trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Explicitly specify the `formatter`. It can be one of the following:

`'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter::class,`

OR

`'formatter' => 'default',`

So, your new `loggly` channel definition would look something like:

```
'loggly' => [
    'driver' => 'monolog',
    'handler' => Monolog\Handler\LogglyHandler::class,
    'formatter' => Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter::class,
    'with' => [
        'token' => env('LOGGLY_KEY'),
        'tag' => str_replace(' ', '_', env('APP_NAME') . '_' . env('APP_ENV')),
    ]
]
```

Comment: The `tag` in the config object didn't work for me. I had to create a customizer to add the tag to the message. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#advanced-monolog-channel-customization