# Laravel log error in channels in json format

Tags: php, json, laravel, logging

As I was logging my data in a file in the laravel framework I observed that every log has an auto-generated string and date:

`[2021-05-24 17:16:54] local.INFO: {"request":"{\"mail_data\":\"[ { \\\"recipients\\\": [  [\\\"email@example.com\\\"] ], \\\"name\\\": \\\"taar\\\", \\\"place\\\": \\\"liverpool\\\", \\\"address\\\": \\\" Test <a href = \\\\\\\"https:\\\\\\/\\\\\\/example.com?\\\\\\\">Click here <\\/a> \\\", \\\"subject\\\": \\\"screen\\\", \\\"from\\\": \\\"no-reply\\\" } ]\",\"test\":\"1\"}"}`

this is not what I want because I want to log my whole data in JSON format I searched but was unable to find any solution to remove `[2021-05-24 17:16:54] local.INFO`

Comment: If you remove the date/time, how will you know what happened when.  Would it be better to add this information to a JSON object and log the whole thing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565321/how-can-i-send-json-formatted-log-entries-to-loggly-with-laravel-5-6

Comment: @NigelRen yes thats what i am doing. storing the time in json object but before that I was aiming to remove all the data outside json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Customizing Monolog For Channels

in config/logging.php

```
'single' => [
    'driver' => 'single',
    'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter::class],
    'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
    'level' => 'debug',
],
```

and write Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class CustomizeFormatter
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(
                '[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer official documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels

Comment: that's a great idea let me check for the same

Comment: if you are using single channel then make sure to update logging.php with 'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),

Comment: @JonasBoshen.glad to here  that you resolved your issue.

Comment: Hi @JohnLobo is there any way that I can define %datetime% format like i want it to be [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss]  is there any way it can be done